# Error when using for each in instance variable

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to loop all my array and trying to compare the value of my json id with the one im passing true a method. But when I try to do it, I get an error:

`undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

heroe.rb

```
require 'json'

class Hero
  attr_accessor :hp

  json = File.read('skill_list.json')
  @skills = JSON.parse(json)

  def initialize(name, level, job, hp, strength)
    @name = name
    @level = level.to_i
    @job = job
    @hp = hp.to_i
    @strength = strength.to_i
  end

  def get_name
    @name
  end

  def profile
    puts "#{@name} level is #{@level} and hp: #{@hp}"
  end

  def attack(id)
    @skills.each do |s|
      if s['id'] == id
        puts true
      else
        puts false
      end
    end
  end

  def get_hp
    puts @hp
  end
end
```

skill_list.json

```
[
  {
  "id": 0,
  "name": "Double Slash",
  "element": "fighter",
  "amp": 1.1,
  "mp": 1
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Slash",
    "element": "fighter",
    "amp": 1,
    "mp": 1
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Falling Ashes",
    "element": "psychic",
    "amp": 1,
    "mp": 1
  }
]
```

Then I called the object with the attack method: `hero.attack(1)`

I'm kinda stuck here, any help will be appreciated~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that `@skills` is declared in the class context which makes it a property of the class, not of any instances. Instance methods have their own individual context which is unrelated to this. Like `MyClass.a` and `MyClass#a` are different things, the same too applies here.

Fixing this is merely a case of loading that data once into a class method with a lazy initializer:

```
class Hero
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :hp
  attr_accessor :level
  attr_accessor :strength

  def self.skills
    @skills ||= JSON.parse(File.open('skill_list.json'))
  end

  def initialize(name, level, job, hp, strength)
    @name = name
    @level = level.to_i
    @job = job
    @hp = hp.to_i
    @strength = strength.to_i
  end

  def profile
    puts "#{name} level is #{level} and hp: #{hp}"
  end

  def attack(id)
    self.class.skills.each do |s|
      if s['id'] == id
        puts true
      else
        puts false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You're also using `attr_accessor` correctly for `hp` but then go and define a very non-Ruby-like `get_hp` method which is completely extraneous. You can get rid of that and the other `get_` method by using accessors for every property.

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked! Can you explain me what ||= means? First time I've seen this in ruby.

Comment: `x ||= y` is the same thing as `x = x || y` which is a convenient way of saying "assign `y` to `x` unless `x` is already a non-*logically-false* value." In short: Only initialize `x` if `x` has not been initialized already. This is called "lazy loading" because that block is intended to run once and once only. Note that when threads are involved this gets tricky, but the same principle can be applied using an automatic lock.

Comment: There are variants like `&&=` which also work using the same expansion principle, but since it's rare you'd want to assign to `x` only if it'd already been assigned something, it's not something you're likely to see in production code. `+=`, `-=`, `*=` and `/=` are more common, though, where `x +=1` is the same as `x = x + 1`.

Comment: Oh! I now understand! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Since instance variables must be declared either on the initialize method or on other instance method) and not just within the class.
I think **you should put the following within the initialize method**.

```
  json = File.read('skill_list.json')
  @skills = JSON.parse(json)
```

or **move @skills into a SKILLS constant** instead so that it will only be called once.

```
class Hero
  attr_accessor :hp

  SKILLS = JSON.parse(File.read('skill_list.json'))

  # ...
end
```